# Android adapter architecture

Tags: android, user-interface

While coding my current project I've encountered a lot of list views. For every ListView I wrote a BaseAdapter. My problem is manipulating views are done in adapter every time and this caused huge sized adapters. Listeners for drag, click and long click are always inside the adapter. Is there a better approach? Is extending the appropriate View class logical?

Comment: I don't define my listeners inside the adapter, I agree with the "huge sized/lots of adapters statement". For every slightly different listview I have to create a new arrayadapter with another listitem.xml etc.